# Parse WDSL Types using XSOM parser

Tags: java, types, wsdl, xsom

I have a wsdl with the following structure:

```
<wsdl:definitions>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema>
            <xs:element name="elem1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema>
            <xs:element ref="elem1"/> 
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <OTHER WSDL ELEMENTS HERE BUT NOT SHOWN FOR BREVITY>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

How can we extract XSResultSet using XSOM parser on this wsdl?